# Change UITableViewCell height based on UIVIew

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a UIView that changes height based on the amount of content in it. It's basically a list of tags. I am not sure how to adjust the row height based on the height of the tagView. Also when it goes to a smaller iPhone screen the height of the tagView also adjusts. I know how to work with images as this example demonstrates very well: [How to resize UIImageView based on UIImage's size/ratio in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154784/how-to-resize-uiimageview-based-on-uiimages-size-ratio-in-swift-3/41155070#41155070). But I am not sure how to work with a tagView which is a type of `UIView`.

I am using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` but this is not affecting the cell which contains the tags.

As you can see below the content just goes over the cell:

[image]

Comment: How do you add tag views to cell?

Comment: Same way I add any other UIView element to a cell like a photo etc. By defining it and adding the constraints.

Comment: Have you set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0(any value)` and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` both?
[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Ok I got it to work, I was not setting it up properly. But the issue now is the padding on the bottom seems really large the more tags I have

Comment: Great, What was the issue?
Also, I would suggest change adding view and replace it with `UICollectionView` if possible.

Comment: Quite a minor issue I was calling `addSubview(tagView)` instead of `contentView.addSubview(tagView)`. I'm not sure why you're suggesting I use a `UICollectionView`?

Comment: So that easily you can add cells, instead of adding multiple `UIView`s.

Comment: I see, this doesn't seem to be an issue as for the tags I'm using a library which does all of this for me. It wraps inside a dynamic view. That's why I asked this question. But I am now having problems where there is a large space at the bottom of my tags when I add more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162526/discussion-between-mninety5-and-zaid-pathan).