# How to make UIImage width be equal to view's width and proportional height inside a custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to download an image and place it in a custom cell, which contains the UIImage and UITextView. I need it to equal to the width of the screen and have the height proportional, similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154784/how-to-resize-uiimageview-based-on-uiimages-size-ratio-in-swift-3/41155070) but I am not sure how to use this convert the answer to use custom table cells. While trying to set the image width and height in `tableView:cellForRowAt` calling the `cell.storedImage.frame.width` and `height` Xcode says it is only a `get-only` property. This is what I thought would work

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] != nil {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageNotesData", for: indexPath) as! ImageNotesCell
        cell.notes.delegate = self
        cell.notes.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.notes.text = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
        guard let imageFirebasePath = tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] else {
            return cell }
        let pathReference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: imageFirebasePath as! String)
        pathReference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1614 * 1614) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                //let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                //cell.storedImage.image = image


                let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:self.view.frame.width
                    ,height:500))
                let imageView = UIImageView()
                if let image = UIImage(data:data!) {
                    let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height
                    if containerView.frame.width > containerView.frame.height {
                        let newHeight = containerView.frame.width / ratio
                        imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: containerView.frame.width, height: newHeight)
                        cell.storedImage.frame.height = newHeight
                    }
                    else{
                        let newWidth = containerView.frame.height * ratio
                        imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: containerView.frame.height)
                        cell.storedImage.frame.width = newWidth
                    }
                }
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                cell.storedImage.image = image
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notesData", for: indexPath) as! NotesCell
        //let noteString = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
        cell.notes.text = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
        cell.notes.delegate = self
        cell.notes.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
}
```

I have also tried using auto layout to fix the problem by having the a text view below it have two different bottom margin constraints but it still doesn't look right. This is the closet I gotten with auto layout constraints. Currently the image view has 0 space constraints on every side to super view

[image]

I assume that the code snippet is the path I should go with but I am not sure how to make the image to look right.

Comment: Did u solve this ?

Comment: No I have not and I just dropped it.

Comment: tell me the issue shortly. Do u need gap between Image and Label ?

Comment: @LampPost Did you solve your problem thanks to my answer or something else ? if you found an answer yourself feel free to share it and have it as an answer, you never know who might come looking for it or if my answer helped feel free to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could still use dynamic constraints, once you get your image you set the aspect ratio constraint for your uiimageview, but it would probably end up being more of a hassle to do.

you can also do this with the frame directly, but you'll need to make a new CGRect for the frame, you can't simply edit it's width or height directly.

you should also set the height of the row to be correct

[tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview)

I'm assuming you've got your ImageNotesCell has it's default size set in the initialiser with notes some kind of uitextfield/uitextview inherited class and storedImage simply an image

```
class ImageNotesCell: UITableViewCell {
  func setImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    let previousNotesFrame = notes.frame
    let ratio = image.size.height / image.size.width
    storedImage.image = image
    let newImageFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.width * ratio)
    let newNotesFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: newImageFrame.size.height + your_spacing_here, width: frame.size.width, height: previousNotesFrame.size.height)
    frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: newImageFrame.size.height + your_spacing_here + newNotesFrame.size.height)
    storedImage.frame = newImageFrame
    notes.frame = newNotesFrame
  }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] != nil {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageNotesData", for: indexPath) as! ImageNotesCell
        cell.notes.delegate = self
        cell.notes.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.notes.text = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
        guard let imageFirebasePath = tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] else {
            return cell }
        let pathReference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: imageFirebasePath as! String)
        pathReference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1614 * 1614) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                cell.setImage(image)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notesData", for: indexPath) as! NotesCell
        //let noteString = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
        cell.notes.text = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
        cell.notes.delegate = self
        cell.notes.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] != nil {
        guard let imageFirebasePath = tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] else {
            return your_default_height_here }
        let pathReference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: imageFirebasePath as! String)
        pathReference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1614 * 1614) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                let ratio = image.size.height / image.size.width
                return (tableView.frame.size.width * ratio) + your_spacing_value_here + your_notes_height_here
            }
        }
    } else {
        return your_notes_cell_height_here
    }
}
```

I tested the logic on a custom UITableViewCell I made and with 3 different image dimensions and notes. it fills up the screen. but since I don't know you ImageNotesCell class among other things I'll leave it to you to adapt but here's the gist of it:

ImageNotesCell class:

- add a function to set an image to the cell which will in turn update the cell, the note and image's frames

Controller class:

- cellForRow: initialise your cell, set it up as usual for the notes part and for when there aren't any images, call the setImage method, return your cell
- heightForRow: return the usual height for when there isn't an image to load, get your image, calculate it's height/width ratio, multiply that by the tableView width, add the value for your spacing, add the height of your notes

Comment: Updated with more info on `cellForRowAt`