# How to set a UICollectionViewCell's height based on the aspect ratio of it's child image?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, nib, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I want to show images of different dimensions (800x600, 800x800, 800x1200 etc) in a collection view (each image is one cell). The **width of the cell is static** and equal to the width of the collection view, but **the height needs to be dynamic**, calculated based on the displayed image, so that we never crop any artwork!

I am using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` and load cells from dedicated nibs like this:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "Image", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell")
```

and then

```
private func cell(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: Item) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell...
    cell.setup(...)
    return cell
}
```

The `ImageCell` only has one image view constrained to its superview (the cell's `contentView`):

[image: cell]

The layout for this cell is using an `.estimated` height:

```
private func createImageSectionLayout() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(20)))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(20)), subitems: [item])
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.interGroupSpacing = 16
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 16, trailing: 16)
    return section
}
```

Finally, I'm using `ScaledHeightImageView`, a `UIImageView` subclass that calculates the intrinsic size based on its image's aspect ratio (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48937190/289501)).

Now the problem is that when I setup the cell and calculate the intrinsic size, the imageView's width is **the one from the storyboard**, and not the one from the parent `UICollectionView`, so my cell's height is always wrong.

Can someone help me understand what is wrong with my setup?

I have tried to experiment with:

- setting up the cell in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
- overriding `layoutSubviews()` in the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass
- calling `layoutIfNeeded()` from several places

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you get your cells to auto-size their heights using a Flow layout?

Comment: @DonMag this is part of a rather complex collection view which is already using compositional layout

Comment: Sure... however, I'd suggest trying to get that `ScaledHeightImageView` cell to work in a basic flow layout first. If it's not working there, you may just be chasing the wrong thing trying to get it working in a compositional layout.